# Return default value for unknown keys in CouchDB query

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I created a view in couchDB and I was able to query and get value for a key.

But, if I query it with some key which doesn't exists in that view, it returns nothing, instead I would like to add some default value to be returned in such case.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that in your application.

Comment: I am using couch rest api to get data and I dont have any backend web services, so is it not possible with it?

Comment: From what I know, there's no such thing that let your fallback when no keys are found. Maybe there is something to do with the lists (server side rendering) but  I think it's going to be deprecated...